# NFS File Sync on Mount

Tags: ubuntu, mount, nfs, fstab

I have an ext4 hard drive mounted and working correctly except, if I add a file/folder to the mount on the server side, I can't see the changes on the client side unless I reboot the client. i.e. The client doesn't know/see the changes to the mount.

`fstab`:

```
server:/mnt/hdd     /home/jesse/mnt/hdd nfs4    _netdev,auto    0   0
```

`etc/exports`:

```
/mnt/hdd 1.2.3.4(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

Files permission are good as I can r&w without any problems. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you plase add the relevant lines from the server's `/etc/exports` file to your question?

Comment: `/mnt/hdd   1.2.3.4(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)`

Comment: Can you provide the output from `mount` on the client side?